# Change background image for TextView at runtime

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm developing my first app and I need to display a larger image of a thumbnail that I click on to be set as the background for a text in a different fragment.

I'm trying to change the background image for a textview using

```
textView.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.user_placeholder_image));
```

In order to minimize the bandwidth usage, I was hoping to download the backdrop image only when the thumbnail is clicked. In other words, is there a way to store resources to the drawable folder at runtime? If not, then is there any other alternative?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not store them in your resources at runtime. However you can always store them as bitmaps. Take a look at my example.

```
//OnClick
new DownloadImageTask((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1))
        .execute("your url");



private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
ImageView bmImage;

public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
    this.bmImage = bmImage;
}

protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
    String urldisplay = urls[0];
    Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
    try {
        InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
        mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return mIcon11;
}

protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
    bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
}
}
```

Instead of setting the image to your ImageView, you could modify the code to store it.

Comment: Thanks! I had initially thought of using a bitmap. I overrode `onBitmapLoaded()` to load from Picasso. It works brilliantly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can not store them in your resources at runtime. But you can store them in SD card or as a bitmap. Later you can load the bitmap or image using any techniques.